# c# how to post FormUrlEncodedContent when object is not flat

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, slack-api, slack

Trying to post to the slack api and have a question on how to include the attachment section in my post. I have a method that will look something like

```
 public KeyValuePair<string, string>[] GetParameters()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", Token));
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("channel", Channel));
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", Text));
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("as_user", As_User.ToString()));
        return parameters.ToArray();
    }
```

But my object has an array I need to include for attachments that looks like

```
public class Attachment
{
    public string text{get; set;}
    public string pretext{ get; set;}
}
```

trying to figure out how to include the attachments in the keyvaluepair array that I'm returning here. Or is that maybe not even the right way to do this?

For what its worth this is how I'm creating the post

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var parameters = response.GetParameters();
                var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
                HttpResponseMessage r = await client.PostAsync(baseurl, requestContent);
                HttpContent responseContent = r.Content;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we talk about posting a message to a channel with [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) the attachments are just another parameter in the request like `token` and `channel`. So you can add `attachments` to your `parameters` in the `GetParameters` method.

The value of `attachments` needs to be an array of attachments in JSON format.

So first convert your `Attachment` object into an array. Then convert it into a JSON string using [JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287.aspx)